# Isn't zip object in Python an iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, iterable

I'm reading 'Introducing Python' by Bill Lubanovic and it says that

> Like zip(), range() returns an iterable object,

But isn't this an incorrect statement? For example,

```
s= zip([1,2,3],['one','two','three'])
next(s)
>> (1,'one')
next(s)
>> (2,'two')

a = range(10)
next(a)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-7b3ad3809256> in <module>()
      1 a = range(10)
----> 2 next(a)

TypeError: 'range' object is not an iterator
```

From the code above, we can check that zip() returns an iterator not an iterable object.

Comment: Which Python version?

Comment: @KlausD. I'm using Python 3.6.1 and the book features Python 3

Comment: `next(s)` returns `(1,'one')`, not `1`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"an iterator" and "iterable" are not the same thing. All iterators are iterable, but not all iterables are iterators.

itera**bles** can be passed to `iter()`, which returns an itera**tor**. itera**tors** can be passed to `next()`, and also can be passed to `iter()`, which acts as the identity function in that case.

---

https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable

> An object capable of returning its members one at a time. Examples of iterables include all sequence types (such as `list`, `str`, and `tuple`) and some non-sequence types like `dict`, file objects, and objects of any classes you define with an `__iter__()` or `__getitem__()` method. Iterables can be used in a for loop and in many other places where a sequence is needed (`zip()`, `map()`, …). When an iterable object is passed as an argument to the built-in function `iter()`, it returns an iterator for the object. This iterator is good for one pass over the set of values. When using iterables, it is usually not necessary to call `iter()` or deal with iterator objects yourself. The for statement does that automatically for you, creating a temporary unnamed variable to hold the iterator for the duration of the loop. See also iterator, sequence, and generator.

https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterator

> An object representing a stream of data. Repeated calls to the iterator’s `__next__()` method (or passing it to the built-in function `next()`) return successive items in the stream. When no more data are available a `StopIteration` exception is raised instead. At this point, the iterator object is exhausted and any further calls to its `__next__()` method just raise `StopIteration` again. Iterators are required to have an `__iter__()` method that returns the iterator object itself so every iterator is also iterable and may be used in most places where other iterables are accepted. One notable exception is code which attempts multiple iteration passes. A container object (such as a list) produces a fresh new iterator each time you pass it to the `iter()` function or use it in a for loop. Attempting this with an iterator will just return the same exhausted iterator object used in the previous iteration pass, making it appear like an empty container.

Answer (score 2):

Iterators are iterable. The fact that `zip` returns an iterator doesn't mean it doesn't return an iterable. Also, if this book was written for Python 2, both `zip` and `range` returned lists in that version.

Comment: What does it mean by 'the fact that zip returns an iterator doesn't mean it doesn't return an iterable'? By the way the book was written for Python 3.

Comment: @Jin: `zip` returns an iterator, but this iterator is also an iterable. The categories are not mutually exclusive; membership in one category does not imply non-membership in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other answers, you might find the `collections.abc` module interesting:

```
>>> from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator
>>> issubclass(zip, Iterable)
True
>>> issubclass(zip, Iterator)
True
>>> issubclass(range, Iterable)
True
>>> issubclass(range, Iterator)
False
```

(note also that `zip` and `range` are classes, not functions anymore, so it is arguably not accurate to speak of them "returning" something)

Comment: Talking about classes returning things is fine. Class or built-in-function-or-method is just an implementation detail; as far as duck typing goes, if you can call it, it's a function.